# I am trying to implement a cooldown system in discord.js, and it works sometimes

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, settimeout

the code below works sometimes and then sometimes does not work. I know this is not the best approach to cooldowns in discord.js but I'd like to learn from this.

Code:

```
        try {
            await interaction.deferReply()

            const query = {
                userId: interaction.member.id
            };
        
            let cooldown = await Cooldown.findOne(query);

            if (cooldown.rob == true) {
                interaction.editReply("lmao you on cooldown noob")
            } else {
                interaction.editReply("no cooldown")
            }

            if (cooldown) {
                if (cooldown.rob == true) { return }

                console.log("cooldown started for" + interaction.user.username)

                cooldown.rob = true
            } else {
                cooldown = new Cooldown({
                    ...query,
                    rob: true
                })
            }

            setTimeout(() => {
                cooldown.rob = false
                console.log("cooldown for" + interaction.user.username)

                cooldown.save()
            }, CooldownTimes.rob)


            await cooldown.save()

        } catch (error) {
            interaction.editReply(
                {
                    embeds: [
                        new EmbedBuilder()
                            .setTitle('ERROR!!!!')
                            .setDescription(error)
                    ]
                }
            )
        }
```

Console output:

```
cooldown started forYet
cooldown forYet
There was an error running this command: Error: Received one or more errors
cooldown started forYet
cooldown forYet
cooldown started forYet
cooldown forYet
There was an error running this command: Error: Received one or more errors
```

The cooldown part of the code works fine, updates db and everything, but every so and then when i try running the command again after the cooldown ends, it does not respond, and the console isn't helpful either. How would i show the code's errors and possibly fix it. (I use a command and event handler)

Comment: The feature you are trying to implement is called throttling. Try looking into it more